# To disable of total row in JS GRID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

JSGrid for a financial web part in Project Server 2013.i wanted to disable of total row,this is not done.I tried to use RegisterCellStyle method.Unfortunately this method does not support the disabled attribute.It just supports textalign or background attribute.Kindly help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the built in method can’t meet your requirement, a suggestion is that, you can applying custom JavaScript or CSS to disable the cell instead.

Some code demos about disabling HTML table using JavaScript in the thread below would be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899453/how-to-disable-and-enable-html-table-using-javascript